# What is the advantage of using AngularJS dependency Injection?

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS Does dependency Injection i want to know what is the meaning of Dependency Injection and the benefit.Why we use dependency Injection.

Comment: need a coding example for my question

Comment: You can check: http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/angularjs-dependency-injection-demystified/. This is literally a Google search first page result.

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide -
 Why Depencency Injection?](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#why-dependency-injection-)